# EclipseLink native query result into POJO - Missing descriptor for [Class]

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink to run some Native SQL. I need to return the data into a POJO.  I followed the instructions at [EclipseLink Docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/2.1/AdvancedJPA_Queries), but I receive the error `Missing descriptor for [Class]`

The query columns have been named to match the member variables of the POJO.  Do I need to do some additional mapping?

POJO:

```
public class AnnouncementRecipientsFlattenedDTO {

        private BigDecimal announcementId;
        private String recipientAddress;
        private String type;

        public AnnouncementRecipientsFlattenedDTO() {
            super();
        }

        public AnnouncementRecipientsFlattenedDTO(BigDecimal announcementId, String recipientAddress, String type) {
            super();
            this.announcementId = announcementId;
            this.recipientAddress = recipientAddress;
            this.type = type;
        }

    ... Getters/Setters
```

Entity Manager call:

```
public List<AnnouncementRecipientsFlattenedDTO> getNormalizedRecipientsForAnnouncement(int announcementId) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery(AnnouncementDeliveryLog.FIND_NORMALIZED_RECIPIENTS_FOR_ANNOUNCEMENT, AnnouncementRecipientsFlattenedDTO.class);
    query.setParameter(1, announcementId);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out you can put the results of a Native Query execution into a List of Arrays that hold Objects.  Then one can iterate over the list and Array elements and build the desired Entity objects.

```
List<Object[]> rawResultList;

    Query query =
        em.createNamedQuery(AnnouncementDeliveryLog.FIND_NORMALIZED_RECIPIENTS_FOR_ANNOUNCEMENT);
    rawResultList = query.getResultList();

    for (Object[] resultElement : rawResultList) {
        AnnouncementDeliveryLog adl = new AnnouncementDeliveryLog(getAnnouncementById(announcementId), (String)resultElement[1], (String)resultElement[2], "TO_SEND");
        persistAnnouncementDeliveryLog(adl);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can only use native SQL queries with a class if the class is mapped.  You need to define the AnnouncementRecipientsFlattenedDTO class as an @Entity.

Otherwise just create the native query with only the SQL and get an array of the data back and construct your DTO yourself using the data.

Comment: Does the Entity have to be associated with a table or can it be free standing?

Comment: Definitely this is the answer to solve the problem. Just in case you would like to map to DTO then you can user @SqlResultSetMapping

Answer (score 9):

Old question but may be following solution will help someone else.

Suppose you want to return a list of columns, data type and data length for a given table in Oracle. I have written below a native sample query for this:

```
  private static final String TABLE_COLUMNS = "select utc.COLUMN_NAME, utc.DATA_TYPE, utc.DATA_LENGTH "
        + "from user_tab_columns utc "
        + "where utc.table_name = ? "                
        + "order by utc.column_name asc";
```

Now the requirement is to construct a list of POJO from the result of above query.

Define `TableColumn` entity class as below:

```
@Entity
public class TableColumn implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "COLUMN_NAME")
private String columnName;
@Column(name = "DATA_TYPE")
private String dataType;
@Column(name = "DATA_LENGTH")
private int dataLength;

public String getColumnName() {
    return columnName;
}

public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
    this.columnName = columnName;
}

public String getDataType() {
    return dataType;
}

public void setDataType(String dataType) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
}

public int getDataLength() {
    return dataLength;
}

public void setDataLength(int dataLength) {
    this.dataLength = dataLength;
}

public TableColumn(String columnName, String dataType, int dataLength) {
    this.columnName = columnName;
    this.dataType = dataType;
    this.dataLength = dataLength;
}

public TableColumn(String columnName) {
    this.columnName = columnName;
}

public TableColumn() {
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (columnName != null ? columnName.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {

    if (!(object instanceof TableColumn)) {
        return false;
    }
    TableColumn other = (TableColumn) object;
    if ((this.columnName == null && other.columnName != null) || (this.columnName != null && !this.columnName.equals(other.columnName))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getColumnName();
}

}
```

Now we are ready to construct a list of POJO. Use the sample code below to construct get your result as List of POJOs.

```
public List<TableColumn> findTableColumns(String table) {
    List<TableColumn> listTables = new ArrayList<>();
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(TABLE_COLUMNS, TableColumn.class).setParameter(1, table);
    listTables = q.getResultList();
    em.close();
    return listTables;
}
```

Comment: This creates a new Table in DB named TableColumn. Any other solution?

Comment: @scarface You seem to have set [`javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm#sthref1908) to something other than `none`. There are many reasons to avoid generating tables with JPA: your application should probably not have permissions to alter the layout. Also JPA’s capabilities are limited (for example, no support for partial indexes afaik). I recommend turning table creation by JPA off, using SQL scripts to create the tables and using a less privileged account for the application.

Answer (score 9):

Also, don't forget to add in your POJO class in `persistence.xml`!  It can be easy to overlook if you are used to your IDE managing that file for you.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same kind of problem where I wanted to return a List of POJOs, and really just POJOs (call it DTO if you want) and not @Entity annotated Objects.

```
class PojoExample {

  String name;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  SomeEnum type;

  public PojoExample(String name, SomeEnum type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

With the following Query:

```
String query = "SELECT b.name, a.newtype as type FROM tablea a, tableb b where a.tableb_id = b_id";

Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query, "PojoExample");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<PojoExample> data = query.getResultList();
```

Creates the PojoExample from the database without the need for an Entity annotation on PojoExample. You can find the method call in the [Oracle Docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

edit:
As it turns out you have to use @SqlResultSetMapping for this to work, otherwise your query.getResultList() returns a List of Object.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "PojoExample", 
  classes = @ConstructorResult(columns = {
    @ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class), 
    @ColumnResult(name = "type", type = String.class)
  }, 
  targetClass = PojoExample.class)
 )
```

Just put this anywhere under your @Entity annotation (so in this example either in tablea or tableb because PojoExample has no @Entity annotation)