# How to fix missing descriptor for class POJO after update server?

Tags: java, sql, websphere-9

I am having issue with code that use Native query below:

```
public Result<IDto> getSearchResult(String classID, Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize
            , String orderBy, String orderType,String language){                        

        TrainingFeedbackReportDetailDTO reportDetailDTO = new TrainingFeedbackReportDetailDTO();

        //add information of class into response
        TrainingFeedbackReportDTO classInfo = DaoManager.getTrainingFeedbackReportDao().getClassInfo(classID,language);
        reportDetailDTO.setClassInfo(classInfo);

        //add agent list with list of question & answer for each agent
        AgentResponseDTO agentResponse = new AgentResponseDTO();
        reportDetailDTO.setAgentResponse(agentResponse);

        Map<Integer, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        String sqlStatement = getAgentInfo(classID, orderBy, orderType, paramMap, language);

        //get list of agent register for specific class
        List<IDto> agentResponseList = getResult(sqlStatement, pageNo, pageSize, paramMap, AgentFeedbackDTO.class.getName());       
        Integer totalRecord = getResult(sqlStatement, 0, 0, paramMap, AgentFeedbackDTO.class.getName()).size();                         

        agentResponse.setTotalRecord(totalRecord);
        //get list of question & answer for each class & agent
        agentResponse.setDataList(getAgentFeedbackDetail(classID, agentResponseList));      
        reportDetailDTO.setAgentResponse(agentResponse);

        Result<IDto> result = new Result<IDto>();
        result.setData(reportDetailDTO);
        return result;      

    }

private String getAgentInfo(String classID, String orderBy, String orderType, 
            Map<Integer, Object> paramMap, String language){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT  tmp0.agent_id agentID, tmp0.agent_code agentCode, tmp0.agent_name agentName, tmp0.agent_name_thai agentNameThai,  ");
        builder.append(         "tmp0.division division, tmp0.agency_code agencyCode, tmp0.agency_name_th agencyNameTh, tmp0.agency_name_en agencyNameEn ");
        builder.append("FROM (" + getAgentFinishFeedback() + ") ac ");
        builder.append("INNER JOIN (" + getAgentInfo() + ") tmp0 ON tmp0.agent_id=ac.FK_AGENT_ID ");
        builder.append("WHERE ac.FK_CLASS_ID=?1 ");
        if (orderBy.isEmpty()){
            orderBy = "agentID";
            orderType = "ASC";
        }
        if(orderBy.equals("agencyName")) {
            if(language.equals(Constant.HTTP_LANGUAGE_EN)) {
                orderBy = "agencyNameEn";
            } else {
                orderBy = "agencyNameTh";
            }
        }
        builder.append("ORDER BY " + orderBy + " " + orderType);
        paramMap.put(1, new BigDecimal(classID));       
        return builder.toString();
    }

private List<IDto> getResult(String sqlStatement, Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize, 
            Map<Integer, Object> paramMap, String dtoClassName){
        List<IDto> list = getList(sqlStatement, pageNo, pageSize, paramMap, dtoClassName);
        if (list.size() > 0){
            return list;
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<IDto>();
        }
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List<IDto> getList(String sqlStatement, Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize, 
            Map<Integer, Object> paramMap, String dtoClassName){
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = PersistenceManager.getLMSEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlStatement, Class.forName(dtoClassName));
            if (paramMap != null) {
                for (Integer name : paramMap.keySet()) {
                    query.setParameter(name, paramMap.get(name));
                }
            }
            if (pageSize > 0){
                query                   
                    .setMaxResults(pageSize)
                    .setFirstResult(pageNo*pageSize);
            }
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (em!=null){
                em.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My POJO code:

```
package com.aia.lms.dto;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.aia.lms.persistence.entity.IEntity;

public class AgentFeedbackDTO implements IDto, IExtractDto{

    private String agentCode;
    private String agentNameThai;
    private String division;
    private String agencyCode;
    private String agencyName;
    private String agencyNameTh;
    private String agencyNameEn;

    private BigDecimal agentID;
    private String agentName;
    private List<ShortFeedbackDTO> questions = new ArrayList<ShortFeedbackDTO>();


    public String getAgencyName() {
        return agencyName;
    }
    public void setAgencyName(String agencyName) {
        this.agencyName = agencyName;
    }
    public BigDecimal getAgentID() {
        return agentID;
    }
    public void setAgentID(BigDecimal agentID) {
        this.agentID = agentID;
    }
    public String getAgentCode() {
        return agentCode;
    }
    public void setAgentCode(String agentCode) {
        this.agentCode = agentCode;
    }
    public String getAgentName() {
        return agentName;
    }
    public void setAgentName(String agentName) {
        this.agentName = agentName;
    }
    public String getDivision() {
        return division;
    }
    public void setDivision(String division) {
        this.division = division;
    }
    public String getAgencyCode() {
        return agencyCode;
    }
    public void setAgencyCode(String agencyCode) {
        this.agencyCode = agencyCode;
    }


    public String getAgencyNameTh() {
        return agencyNameTh;
    }
    public void setAgencyNameTh(String agencyNameTh) {
        this.agencyNameTh = agencyNameTh;
    }
    public String getAgencyNameEn() {
        return agencyNameEn;
    }
    public void setAgencyNameEn(String agencyNameEn) {
        this.agencyNameEn = agencyNameEn;
    }
    public String getAgentNameThai() {
        return agentNameThai;
    }
    public void setAgentNameThai(String agentNameThai) {
        this.agentNameThai = agentNameThai;
    }
    public List<ShortFeedbackDTO> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }
    public void setQuestions(List<ShortFeedbackDTO> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
    public void setFeedback(ShortFeedbackDTO feedback){     
        for (ShortFeedbackDTO dto : this.questions){
            if (dto.isExist(feedback.getDetailID())){
                return;
            }
        }       
        this.questions.add(feedback);   
        Collections.sort(this.questions);
    }
    @Override
    public IDto extractParent(IEntity entry) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDTO(IEntity entry) {
    }

}
```

These code run normally when I use Websphere server 8.5 with Java 6 and JPA 1.1. But after updating to Websphere server 9.0 with Java 8 and JPA 2.0, the system get issue as below:

```
[5/27/20 14:40:40:157 ICT] 000000b7 eclipselink   W   Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.8.WAS-v20181218-0accd7f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class com.aia.lms.dto.AgentFeedbackDTO].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=AgentFeedbackDTO sql="SELECT     tmp0.agent_id agentID, tmp0.agent_code agentCode, tmp0.agent_name agentName, tmp0.agent_name_thai agentNameThai,  tmp0.division division, tmp0.agency_code agencyCode, tmp0.agency_name_th agencyNameTh, tmp0.agency_name_en agencyNameEn FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ctf.FK_AGENT_ID, ctf.FK_CLASS_ID FROM LMS_CLASS_TRAINING_FEEDBACK ctf        LEFT JOIN LMS_AGENT_CLASS LAC ON LAC.FK_AGENT_ID = ctf.FK_AGENT_ID AND LAC.FK_CLASS_ID = ctf.FK_CLASS_ID     WHERE LAC.FK_CLASS_ENROLL_STATUS_ID = 1) ac INNER JOIN ( SELECT  ui.ID agent_id,          CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN LP.PROSPECT_CODE ELSE ai.AGENT_CODE END agent_code,       CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  CONCAT(CONCAT(LP.AGENT_FIRSTNAME_EN, '  '),LP.AGENT_SURNAME_EN) ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(ai.AGENT_FIRSTNAME_EN, '  '),ai.AGENT_SURNAME_EN) END agent_name,         CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN   LP.AGENT_NAME_THAI ELSE ai.AGENT_NAME_THAI END agent_name_thai,         CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  NVL(LHS2.DIVISION_CODE, ' ') ELSE NVL(LHS.DIVISION_CODE, ' ') END division,      CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  NVL(lai.AGENCY_CODE, ' ') ELSE NVL(ai.AGENCY_CODE, ' ') END agency_code,         CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  NVL(lai.AGENCY_NAME_THAI, ' ') ELSE NVL(ai.AGENCY_NAME_THAI, ' ') END agency_name_th,        CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  NVL(lai.AGENCY_NAME_ENG, ' ') ELSE NVL(ai.AGENCY_NAME_ENG, ' ') END agency_name_en   FROM LMS_USER_INFO ui     LEFT JOIN LMS_AGENT_INFO ai ON ui.ID=ai.FK_USER_INFO_ID       LEFT JOIN LMS_HIERARCHY_SETUP LHS ON LHS.AGENCY_CODE = ai.AGENCY_CODE          LEFT JOIN LMS_PROSPECT LP ON LP.FK_USER_INFO_ID = ui.ID       LEFT JOIN (          SELECT FK_USER_INFO_ID,LUR.NAME           FROM LMS_USER_INFO_ROLE LUIR          LEFT JOIN LMS_USER_ROLE LUR           ON LUIR.FK_USER_ROLE_ID = LUR.ID     WHERE LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' ) LUR           ON LUR.FK_USER_INFO_ID = LP.FK_USER_INFO_ID     LEFT JOIN LMS_AGENT_INFO lai         ON lai.FK_USER_INFO_ID = LP.CREATED_BY      LEFT JOIN LMS_HIERARCHY_SETUP LHS2 ON LHS2.AGENCY_CODE = lai.AGENCY_CODE    ) tmp0 ON tmp0.agent_id=ac.FK_AGENT_ID WHERE ac.FK_CLASS_ID=?1 ORDER BY agentCode ASC")
[5/27/20 14:40:40:611 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.8.WAS-v20181218-0accd7f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class com.aia.lms.dto.AgentFeedbackDTO].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=AgentFeedbackDTO sql="SELECT     tmp0.agent_id agentID, tmp0.agent_code agentCode, tmp0.agent_name agentName, tmp0.agent_name_thai agentNameThai,  tmp0.division division, tmp0.agency_code agencyCode, tmp0.agency_name_th agencyNameTh, tmp0.agency_name_en agencyNameEn FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ctf.FK_AGENT_ID, ctf.FK_CLASS_ID FROM LMS_CLASS_TRAINING_FEEDBACK ctf        LEFT JOIN LMS_AGENT_CLASS LAC ON LAC.FK_AGENT_ID = ctf.FK_AGENT_ID AND LAC.FK_CLASS_ID = ctf.FK_CLASS_ID     WHERE LAC.FK_CLASS_ENROLL_STATUS_ID = 1) ac INNER JOIN ( SELECT  ui.ID agent_id,          CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN LP.PROSPECT_CODE ELSE ai.AGENT_CODE END agent_code,       CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  CONCAT(CONCAT(LP.AGENT_FIRSTNAME_EN, '  '),LP.AGENT_SURNAME_EN) ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(ai.AGENT_FIRSTNAME_EN, '  '),ai.AGENT_SURNAME_EN) END agent_name,         CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN   LP.AGENT_NAME_THAI ELSE ai.AGENT_NAME_THAI END agent_name_thai,         CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  NVL(LHS2.DIVISION_CODE, ' ') ELSE NVL(LHS.DIVISION_CODE, ' ') END division,      CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  NVL(lai.AGENCY_CODE, ' ') ELSE NVL(ai.AGENCY_CODE, ' ') END agency_code,         CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  NVL(lai.AGENCY_NAME_THAI, ' ') ELSE NVL(ai.AGENCY_NAME_THAI, ' ') END agency_name_th,        CASE WHEN  LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' THEN  NVL(lai.AGENCY_NAME_ENG, ' ') ELSE NVL(ai.AGENCY_NAME_ENG, ' ') END agency_name_en   FROM LMS_USER_INFO ui     LEFT JOIN LMS_AGENT_INFO ai ON ui.ID=ai.FK_USER_INFO_ID       LEFT JOIN LMS_HIERARCHY_SETUP LHS ON LHS.AGENCY_CODE = ai.AGENCY_CODE          LEFT JOIN LMS_PROSPECT LP ON LP.FK_USER_INFO_ID = ui.ID       LEFT JOIN (          SELECT FK_USER_INFO_ID,LUR.NAME           FROM LMS_USER_INFO_ROLE LUIR          LEFT JOIN LMS_USER_ROLE LUR           ON LUIR.FK_USER_ROLE_ID = LUR.ID     WHERE LUR.NAME = 'PROSPECT' ) LUR           ON LUR.FK_USER_INFO_ID = LP.FK_USER_INFO_ID     LEFT JOIN LMS_AGENT_INFO lai         ON lai.FK_USER_INFO_ID = LP.CREATED_BY      LEFT JOIN LMS_HIERARCHY_SETUP LHS2 ON LHS2.AGENCY_CODE = lai.AGENCY_CODE    ) tmp0 ON tmp0.agent_id=ac.FK_AGENT_ID WHERE ac.FK_CLASS_ID=?1 ORDER BY agentCode ASC")
[5/27/20 14:40:40:611 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:484)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:612 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.aia.lms.persistence.dao.TrainingFeedbackReportDetailDao.getList(TrainingFeedbackReportDetailDao.java:244)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:612 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.aia.lms.persistence.dao.TrainingFeedbackReportDetailDao.getResult(TrainingFeedbackReportDetailDao.java:219)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:612 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.aia.lms.persistence.dao.TrainingFeedbackReportDetailDao.getSearchResult(TrainingFeedbackReportDetailDao.java:43)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:612 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.aia.lms.service.TrainingFeedbackReportService.getPaging(TrainingFeedbackReportService.java:124)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:612 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.aia.lms.rest.RESTResource.getFeedbackPaging(RESTResource.java:3216)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:659)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:108)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.invoke(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:174)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:191)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:613 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsInvoker.invoke(LibertyJaxRsInvoker.java:346)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:614 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:614 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:73)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:614 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:111)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:614 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:309)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:614 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:136)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:614 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:280)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:614 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.endpoint.AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.invoke(AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.java:147)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:614 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.handleRequest(IBMRestServlet.java:187)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.doGet(IBMRestServlet.java:153)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.service(IBMRestServlet.java:133)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:615 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:616 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.aia.lms.filter.ResponseCorsFilter.doFilter(ResponseCorsFilter.java:55)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:616 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:616 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:616 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:616 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:616 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:616 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:617 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:617 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:618 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:618 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:618 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:618 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:618 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:618 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:619 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:619 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:619 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:619 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:619 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[5/27/20 14:40:40:619 ICT] 000000b7 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
```

Anyone help me show how could I resolve this problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EclipseLink native query result into POJO - Missing descriptor for \[Class\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071649/eclipselink-native-query-result-into-pojo-missing-descriptor-for-class)

Comment: Use @Entity annotation for your POJO class. 
You need to map the class as an Entity in order to be able to use the instances of it.

Comment: If I use @Entity anonation for POJO class, system will catch exception : Entity class [class com.aia.lms.dto.AgentFeedbackDTO] has no primary key specified. It should define either an Id anonation, EmbeddedId anonation or an IdClass anonation. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.

Comment: U need to define a primary key .. like `@Id
@Column(name = "agentid")
private BigDecimal agentID;`

Also use `@Column(name = "col-name")`  for other columns of ur entity.